# Please help : Functionality similar to Email2Case

Tags: email2case

We have a requirement of creating custom object records on sending mail similar to `Email2Case`. Email2Case creates Case object on sending email, can we have a custom object record on sending email?

Thanks in advance.

Suha

Comment: Look at apex inboundemailHandler class

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply. Can you pls elaborate.

Comment: Check this out https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com

Comment: follow the link that @Ratan provided, write some code and then, if you get stuck, amend your question with code sample plus identification of problem area; you'll also find that if you do Google search, you'll find more examples of inboundemailhandlers.

Comment: Ok, thanks crop1645 and Ratan for your resplies, will work on it.